How to capture a CardView element in Appium
I need to capture an element in my automated tests with Appium in android, this element is of type CardView https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView and I can't capture it in the Appium Inspector how could I capture it?
I tried using the following selector:
//androidx.cardview.widget.CardView[1]

You can see the component tree here:
Component Tree

Download Appium Inspector
https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector
You will see which selectors to use
